# Why is this simple edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

[This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15140669) simply improves an answer by highlighting key strokes with the `<kbd>` tag.

It was rejected for reason :

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.

Can someone explain how this edit could possibly promote a product ? - If Linux is here considered as the promoted product, the whole answer should be rejected, not only the edit.

Or in what way this edit is "deliberately destructive" ?

Comment: The suggested edit is still being reviewed. It has not yet been rejected.

Comment: You are also not reading the entire reason; the reviewer must've thought it was vandalism, in which case *deliberately destructive* applies. This has nothing to do with Linux or product promotion.

Comment: The suggested edit has now completed review, and has been accepted.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Martijn. Still I can not figure out how "deliberately destructive" my edit is... That was the purpose of the question.

Comment: Edit has now been approved. It does depend on who sees the suggestion and _their_ view of it. I did one yesterday that corrected code formatting and it was actually rejected as being harmful yet copying that same code into the compiler would see it make the exact changes I proposed. It's just the way it is, don't get hung up about it.

Comment: Compilers don't care about code *formatting*, so you obviously fixed something other than formatting, @bugs. If you made this fix in an answer and you knew it to be correct, that's one thing (but people are still liable to reject it). If you made this fix in a *question*, then you shouldn't have and that edit should have been rejected.

Comment: @CodyGray it was an answer. It was clearly typed rather than _compiled_ and unfortunately the author was stating something with the use of `**` which I left in as to be honest it brought light about the changes that the OP needed to know about albeit it would have caused a compile error. The other issues were simply formatting issues which I corrected. In hindsight I probably should have removed the use of `**` and added a note or maybe left a comment for the author. Two guys agreed with my change, 3 others didn't.

Comment: I really don't understand your comment at all. It doesn't make sense to me that you edited an answer to fix an error, yet left the error in there. But I guess you're talking about [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15136017), and yes, that's a reasonable edit…except that (A) you missed capitalizing "Sub", and (B) "Sub" shouldn't even be there at all, since it is a "Function". I don't know why you mentioned "copying that same code into the compiler"—these are superficial formatting changes that the compiler doesn't care about. A better edit summary would've helped. @bug

Comment: @CodyGray sorry I don't mean to cause confusion. The edit wasn't the best I'll admit, I was on my mobile and noticed a few formatting issues which I attempted to correct. The comment I made was merely to say that some people will agree with the edit whilst others won't and it's nothing to get hung up about. Anyway thanks for editing it, much better now.

Answer (score 9):

The edit you linked had *not* been rejected—when this question was posted, it was still in the process of being reviewed.

[The edit has since been approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15140669), although one user did vote to reject it for the cited reason. Clearly it is not promotional or spam, so it must be the second part of the rejection reason that applies: the reviewer thought the edit was "deliberately destructive" and amounted to vandalism.

That may have been taking it too far. However, it is not a very good edit. That answer has a number of formatting and grammar problems that should be fixed. These are much more important than the trivial application of `<kbd>` tags, and since the majority of the answer consists of keys, formatting it in this way arguably *impedes* the readability of the post, rather than improving it.

[Here's how I improved the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30169435/3).

Comment: OK Cody Gray, *lesson learned*. I will have to refrain myself from editing because I don't have skills to improve grammar. English is my second language, I am not a native.

Comment: thanks for removing the annoying boldface from the post in question....